# After adding some columns in SQL Server, how add them to my DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I add new columns to my dataGridView, after I added them to SQL Server?
The columns are not visible in datagridview -> add columns

Comment: Without knowing how your system is setup, I'm guessing you need to Update your datasource to reflect the newest changes to the database. Are you making a WinForm application or another type?

Comment: It's a WinForm application, and yes I want Update my datasource to reflect the newest changes to the database

Comment: when i Right Click on dataGridView and choose add column, there is no new columns that I added to my db

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on your dataset underneath the Data Source menu and choosing the option "Configure Data Source With Wizard", going into the table check marking the new field, then seeing if it comes up under 'add columns'?

Comment: do you know how to edit the datagrid source. also are the columns auto generated or not..? if so then drop the datasource in the designer and re-add or refresh the data sources..

Comment: I add this to InitializeComponent(); , and columns shows in datagrid, but i want to add them by right click to change the property of each column
i used this : dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

Comment: thanks a lot JKirkbride , You were right.
I should go with the wizard

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to add a new column to your DataGridView programatically.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("newColumn","That is right");
```

If you want to avoid the wizard for some reason, this is your next best option.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to right click your data source and refresh it?
[image]

Comment: I refresh, but nothing happened!